# Docker image connecting to SAN

Tags: docker, san

I have Docker load on my Win10 laptop with a SQL Server image. I have created a volume on the laptop to point to an existing database as a POC. Now I need to be able to do the same with a snapshot of SAN drive on my Win10 laptop. I'm using a Nimble SAN. The Nimble docker plugin appears to be available for linux only. Which brings me to the question, Is it possible to connect the SAN snapshot to the Docker CE container on my laptop which is running SQL on Linux? Or have I crossed some serious IT streams?